# how to push the photo and the button to the bottom and make the button take up all the space by css?

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I am trying to cover a website, and here is the screenshot of the design of the website I want to cover

[Design of the notification button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xiWl.png)

But here is my notification button

[My notification button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyKie.png)

As you can see in my notification button's picture, I have some problems.

My first problem is, the picture is not lying in the middle.
My second problem is, the buttons below are too close to the picture and the message line ?

And my third problem is, the size of the buttons below the picture does not match as the design ?

```
https://github.com/anhquanjp/bai110headernotificationcss
```

To solve the first and the second problem, should I make a frames with a width and height as the design and then push the picture and message line down ? So that the buttons will be pushed down too ?

Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71671506/edit) to include the relevant code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st problem `make a new div and move your img inside this div then`

```
.thisdiv{

display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

For 2nd problem give `margin` to top `i.e margin: top/bottom left/right; or simply margin-left,right, top, bottom etc.`

```
button{
margin-top:4vh;
}
```

For 3rd problem, change `padding` of the button as required

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For 3rd problem, I just changed padding of the button but they did not change the properties, so I decided to use height and width of the button, but nothing change, could you please give me any idea or more ?

Comment: kindly share your css properties about button so that the problem could figure out.  You can also check this site for the solution  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp